What is the fundamental difference between Fresnel's reflectivity coeffecient and Bragg's scattering coefficient?
Context: In Chapter 3.1.2, Polarisation properties of surface backscatter, in the book "Polarisation: Applications in Remote Sensing", Dr Cloude explains scattering from a surface using Fresnel's reflectivity equation and the Bragg scattering model. It is noted that the HH component in the Bragg model is equal to the HH equation in Fresnel's but not for the vertical polarization and there is no Brewster angle effect anymore. So I would like to understand it better.

This question is too broad and lacks detailed information.
